# Issue serializing a class that references itself as a property

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

Say this my class that is generated via recursive call:

```
public class Level
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<Level> NextLevel { get; set; }
    public Level()
    {
        NextLevel = new List<Level>();
    }
}
```

However when I try to serialize this to xml I get this error:

> The type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[....ResponseModel+Level, Testing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] may not be used in this context.

I've tried Json serialization and it's fine.

I assume it's having an issue with the `NextLevel` property. Is there a special attribute needed here?

I have not found much info about this.

Comment: Please share your serialization code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serialize lists/arrays using XML Serialization you would generally have to apply the [**`XmlArray`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and [**`XmlArrayItem`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attributes to your property in order to specify that it should serialize it as a nested sequence of XML elements:

```
[XmlArray("NextLevel")]
[XmlArrayItem("Level")]
public List<Level> NextLevel { get; set; }
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! I'll read up more on xml attributes